# Postgres groupby query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to group by the product name and by the date.

[image]

so from the above example, I am expecting to see the result as below. Is it possible . Can some one help me out please.Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but this is as simple as:

```
select product_name,
       date,
       count(*) as cnt
from the_table
group by product_name,
         date
order by product_name
```

---

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. First because it's a reserved word but more importantly because it does not *document* what you store in the column. It could be a "purchase_date", a "sold_date", an "expiry_date", ... ?